# Residue fields of complete non-archimedean fields

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

As Lubin points out below, the claim in my original post (see edits) was false.

**Amended Post**

The book I am reading contains the following theorem:

---

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of complete non-arch. fields with residue fields $k_L$ and $k_K$ resp.

Let $\alpha \in k_L$ be separable over $k_K.$

Then there exists $a \in \mathfrak{O}_L$ such that $a\equiv \alpha \text{ mod } \mathfrak{P}_L$ and

$$[K(a):K]=[k_K(\alpha):k_K].$$

In particular, $K(a)/K$ is unramified.

---

It's the "in particular" bit I'm stuck with. For $K(a)/K$ to be unramified, we need

$$[k_{K(a)}:k_K]\geq[k_K(\alpha):k_K]$$

which, of course(!), doesn't imply that $k_{K(a)}\cong k_K$ as I mistakenly claimed above.

It is this that I am stuck with. Many thanks!

Comment: It’s not true. Take $K=\Bbb Q_2$, $\alpha=2\sqrt2$. Then $\mathfrak O=\Bbb Z_2[\sqrt2]$, with $\sqrt2$ being a uniformizer. But $\alpha=2\sqrt2\mapsto0\in\mathfrak O/\mathfrak P$.

Comment: @Lubin I have found my stupid mistake and editted the question now. Do you have any hints on how to prove this corrected version. Many thanks!

Comment: You are assuming that at least one element of $k_L$ is separable over $k_K$, and you want to prove as a result that $L/K$ is unramified?  This is still clearly false.

Comment: @D_S No: I'm not trying to prove that $L/K$ is unramified but that $K(a)/K$ is unramified.

Comment: Well, in the case that $k$ is finite, it’s easy enough: you take a suitable root of unity in $K$. What do you need to do in the general case? P.S. A certain aged mathematician with failing vision curses you for using both $a$ and $\alpha$ in your question.

Comment: @Lubin Apologies for the unfortunate typesetting! I'm slightly confused, is it not in fact clear that $$k_K(\alpha) \subseteq k_{K(a)}?$$
So, in my original formulation (see edits), I should have had:
$$\mathfrak{O}/\mathfrak{P}\supseteq (\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p})(\bar{\alpha})$$
which is trivial (right?).

Comment: Right you are..

Comment: @Elliptic2005, Have you solved this? I meet with a same problem... It seems the author implicitly assumed (or proved) the residue field of $K(a)$ is $k_K(\alpha)$... But I don't know why